# What layer should i put system integrations when using DDD?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a comum business software that has customers, products and sales.

I need to create a robot that will monitor an folder and import files that has new customers.

I have the following layer (folder) structure on my project:

- Domain

  - Entities
  - Repositories
  - Services
- Infrastructure

  - DataAccess
- Application

  - MyRobotClass.cs

Currently my robot class is in Application layer.

What layer should i put system integrations when using DDD?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of a service

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar situation not too long ago, where we needed a way to monitor a folder to import new customers, and came to the conclusion it is not really part of the primary layers.  It is more of a consumer of the application layer than part of it, similar to the presentation layer.

We ended up putting all code related to the file import within a console application project.  Then we referenced the application layer assembly, and used the standard application handlers for any business related interactions, such as CreateCustomer(..)